# MacBook Pro Retina 15" - 2.2 or 2.5Ghz?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I'm going to purchase a new MBP (May 2015) Retina 15".

I will be using it mainly for software development and programming, Ruby, Rails, Angular JS, Git, and HTML/CSS3.

This probably gets asked a lot but my question is what would the consensus be on upgrading the processor? For £80 I don't mind going up one notch to the 2.5Ghz i7, but unless I'm doing hardcore stuff i.e. graphics/movie editing, am I just throwing money at a wall? Also will time play an effect on the speed of this? i.e. 3-4 years down the line? Will there be a noticeable difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, your best option is to wait until October, when the new Macs come out, but if you can't, I'd go with the 2.5GHz. That extra power will be good if you intend to keep this MacBook around for a few years.

Comment: You said "_your best option is to wait until October, when the new Macs come out_"... Ever hear the investment saying "Past performance is no guarantee of future returns!"? You really have no idea whether or not Apple is going to release a new MacBook Pro in October, it could go either way!  I'm specifically mentioning the MBP as that's what Stussy is considering purchasing although that goes for all Apple hardware products.

Comment: Yes, but especially in the last three or four years Apple has WWDC in June, the iPhone event in late September, and the iPad/Mac event in late October. Sure, maybe Apple won't release new Macs this year, but with Christmas right on the horizon in late-October, one would think that Apple would release new stuff in order to stay competitive.

Comment: What one would think is irrelevant and it can truly go either way. A MBP 15" was released in May, a mid-year release.  Looking at the release dates for all MBP 15' released in October, it only occurred if the earlier release that year was an early-year release.  So if apple follows suit there will not be a 15" MBP in October.  However I'd never explicitly say one way or the other! :)